# UIActivityViewController Automatically 'Clicking' Link iOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have a basic UIActivityViewController sharing some text and a URL. The sharing options are Email, SMS, Twitter, and Facebook. Everything works fine in iOS 6 but in iOS 7 when I choose Twitter or Facebook, without touching anything my device automatically closes my app, opens Safari and goes to the URL I am trying to share. What could be causing this?

Code (CustomActivityItemProvider is a subclass to customize text based on sharer):

```
if ([UIActivityViewController class]) { // if class exists = ios6+

    // Create array for sharing
    CustomActivityItemProvider *textToShare = [[CustomActivityItemProvider alloc]
                                               initWithStandardText:@"Text to share.\n"];

    NSURL *urlToShare = iTunesShort ? iTunesShort : [NSURL URLWithString:iTunesLink];

    NSArray *activityItems = @[textToShare, urlToShare];

    // Show sharing view
    UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]
                                            initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];
    activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypePrint, UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard,
                                         UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll];

    [self presentViewController:activityVC animated:TRUE completion:nil];    
}
```

Comment: can you please upload code.

Comment: i have tested its work perfect. try with diff. url like yahoo pr google, and then tell whats hhpening.

Comment: Yea you were right. www.google.com works fine.

Comment: So there is something in url, what is url about?

Comment: I've narrowed it down to short URLs. The full URL works fine, but if I use a shortening service to produce a short URL I have this problem.

Comment: so its solved your problms.Cheears

Comment: No I'm still having the problem with the short URLs. Any idea why only short URLs would be giving me this problem?

Answer (score 0):

So I still don't know why only shortened URLs were causing this problem, but a solution that took care of it was to include the `urlToShare` in the `textToShare`.

```
// Create array for sharing
NSString *urlToShare = iTunesShort ? iTunesShort : iTunesLink;
NSString *textWithUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Text to share.\n%@", urlToShare];
CustomActivityItemProvider *textToShare = [[CustomActivityItemProvider alloc]
                                           initWithStandardText:textWithUrl];

NSArray *activityItems = @[textToShare];
```